# Lazy Evaluation of expression stored in vector

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

For simplicity, I'm going to vulgarize the whole question.

I am working on boolean arithmetic using only operators OR and AND (for now).

My boolean expressions are stored in a vector alternating a variable and an operator (something like [a, ||, b] for "a OR b").

I would like to know if it is possible to chain back my vector as if I had written:

```
std::vector<xxx> v = {true, &&, (, false, ||, true, )};
// result = true && (false || true) = true
bool result = vector[0] vector[1] vector[2] vector[3] vector[4] vector[5] vector[6];
```

I am aware that arithmetic evaluation algorithms exist (like Shunting-yard) but I would like to avoid using them and use the c++ evaluator instead.
I figured I can overload operators to handle simple expressions but as soon as parenthesis show up I'm stuck.

I apologize if this question has already been asked and answered, I just have no idea what keywords to use in my searches!

Thank you in advance, even just a clue would be nice :)

Comment: Good question. I need the answer to this as well.

Comment: OR is not +. That's XOR. `true + true = false`, `true || true = true`.

Comment: @DeadMG: Hmmm true + true gives true for me. I must be missing something :/ Anyway, I edited my question to use && and ||.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like AxelOmega said - you can use `boost::spirit`. The grammar is pretty simple:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_bool.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <class Iterator>
struct bool_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, bool(), qi::space_type> {
        qi::rule<Iterator, bool(), qi::space_type> rGroup, rBool, rName, rOr, rAnd;

        bool_grammar() : bool_grammar::base_type(rOr) {
                rGroup  = '(' >> rOr >> ')';
                rBool   = qi::bool_ | rGroup;
                rAnd    = rBool[qi::_val = qi::_1] >>
                          *('&' >> rBool[qi::_val = qi::_val && qi::_1]);
                rOr     = rAnd[qi::_val = qi::_1] >>
                          *('|' >> rAnd[qi::_val = qi::_val || qi::_1]);
        }
};
```

you will also need a function to call parser and check results

```
bool parse(const std::string& value) {
        bool_grammar<std::string::const_iterator> g;
        std::string::const_iterator it  = value.begin();
        std::string::const_iterator end = value.end();

        bool s;
        if (qi::phrase_parse(it, end, g, qi::space, s) == false || it != end) {
                // error
        }

        return s;
}
```

and now just merge the `vector` into a single `string` and use the parse function:

```
parse("(true | false) & true | false") ;
```

You can also change the synthesized attribute to some custom class if you are not interested in `bool` result and you want to create a tree that can be manipulated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use expression templates to do this. Some of your boolean literals will have to be like, `bool_(true)` to create the custom object with the appropriate operators, but apart from that, it will be as if you really used C++.

Of course, it's typically simpler to just use a lambda or write a function for this, unless you need to introspect/modify the tree at runtime or something like that.

Comment: It looks like what I need. It apparently allows lazy evaluation which is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't really store raw C++ operators or syntax elements in `vector` of *any* type, so `(`, `*` and so on are out.

You can store them as literals, though:

```
std::vector<std::string> expression = { "2", "+", "3" };
```

However, it's not possible to use "the c++ evaluator" for that; C++ is a compiled language and thus it isn't possible to use the same logic in runtime (Technically it's possible through something like LLVM, but it would most certainly be an overkill). In that case, you're better off with custom evaluator.

It might also be possible in compile time using TMP, but I am not sure that is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
I know I can't store operators directly in my vector, I just simplified my question for clarity. I plan to use custom objects and operators, the main thing I miss is how to "chain back" the elements in my vector like in the example I gave above.

Comment: In that case it would be better to just have something like `double evaluate(vector<string> const& expression)` I guess.

Comment: But it would require an arithmetic evaluator algorithm, wouldn't it ? :)

Comment: *sigh* yes, and that's what I wrote in my answer

Comment: TMP is indeed what I need, I understood it thanks to DeadMG answer. So thank you too!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a file with c++ source code, compile it and run it. Something like this:

```
std::vector<xxx> v = {true, *, (, false, +, true, )};
std::ofstream src("temp.cpp");
src <<
    "#include <iostream>\n"
    "int main() {\n"
    "bool result = ";
for (auto i: v)
    src << i << ' ';
src <<
    ";\n"
    "std::cout << result;\n"
    "}\n";
src.close();
system("g++ temp.cpp -o temp");
system("temp");
```

I ignored various aspects like permissions, temporary file names, output redirection, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Looks fun! It will be too slow for what I need to do though. At least I learned something, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to overload the `,` operator. But this will give you problems when dealing with parentheses. Normally you wont find the correct result by linearly parsing an expression like that.

The normal way of representing expressions is as a tree. And then traverse the tree to compute the final value. The traversal is normally done using recursion.

So its a two staged process

1: Build the tree

2: Recursively evaluate the expression tree

If you want it represented as a graph, look into `boost::graph`

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I also figured overloading , or + would be problematic with parenthesis. Forgot to mention it (will edit).
I could indeed use a tree to represent my expression but I would like to avoid that :)

Comment: Or have a look at properly parsing your expression using `boost::spirit`. I used that coupled with a computation stack to evaluate small expressions at run time once. However do not shy away from graphs, graphs are your friends for solving many computation problems. Why don't you want to use a tree if I may ask?

Comment: I'll take a look at it thanks. I just want to know if it is possible to do what I want in C++ to learn a new "trick". It doesn't look like it's possible though so I will probably go for my plan B, Shunting-Yard or another algorithm.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your answer, you gave me a good advice with boost::spirit :)